# Creating a loop in VBS to write the output in XML

Tags: excel, xml, vba, loops

I want to pull a file from a program and have that file create itself into XML and then run a preset script. its being run through an excel macro
I need this to loop until it reaches a non null value. This is kinda what I have going on, but I can't seem to get this to compile.

```
With ActiveSheet
    For Each Filename In .Range("A2:A" & GetLastRow("Sheet1"))

    
        Set XML = FSO.CreateTextFile( _
                    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ERP" & ".erp", _
                    Overwrite:=True)
       
        With Filename
            XML.WriteLine ("<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>")
            XML.WriteLine ("    <ErpExchange xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">")
            XML.WriteLine ("        <Orders>")
                    Do While BlankFound = False
                      x = x + 1
                    
                                         
                    XML.WriteLine ("            <ErpOrder>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                <ImportType>NewOrder</ImportType>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                <OrderNumber>" & .Offset(x - 1, 1).Value & "</OrderNumber>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                <TargetDate>" & Format(.Offset(x - 1, 2).Value, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss") & "</TargetDate>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                <ProductionStrategy>TargetDateOrder</ProductionStrategy>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                <Automatic>False</Automatic>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                <Parts>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                    <ErpPart>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                        <BysoftCode>" & .Offset(x - 1, 3).Value & "</BysoftCode>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                        <Debit>" & .Offset(x - 1, 4).Value & "</Debit>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                        <Measure>Inch</Measure>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                    </ErpPart>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("                </Parts>")
                    XML.WriteLine ("            </ErpOrder>")
                    If Cells(x, "D").Value = "" Then
                        BlankFound = False
                    ElseIf Cells(x, "D").Value = "Ture" Then
                        BlankFound = True
                    If BlankFound = True Then Exit Do
                    Loop
                        
                        
              XML.WriteLine ("        </Orders>")
            XML.WriteLine ("    </ErpExchange>")
        End With
       
        XML.Close
    Next Filename
End With
```

Comment: @BigBen they mention ASP VBS so that would VBScript in Classic ASP so not sure how that code translates because it does look like VBA.

Comment: If it is Classic ASP, you are definitely talking about VBScript, not VBA but this code will fail in VBScript because named arguments like `FileName:=` are not supported.

Comment: So the code does work.... ish... it will write in XML (even with the FileName:=) but it doesnt do it fully, if at all sometimes. sometimes i get 1 line, other times i get it repeat infinitely until it fills an entire excel sheet.

Comment: @BigBen I'm going off what information the OP has given it clearly says in their recent edit "i havent done any (what used to be ASP but i guess is VBS or VBA)". Classic ASP doesn't use VBA so they are likely confusing something somewhere.

Comment: @VincentDiRosa Can you provide more information on how this code is used, how is it executed? Is it running inside an ASP page or is it inside a COM component or a macro in Excel etc.? The code definitely appears to be VBA but you mention ASP, which is confusing the situation so if you could clarify it would help.

Comment: If you need to write an XML document, why not use the [XMLDOMDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms757878(v=vs.85)) Object? You can do object oriented things like `CreateNode` and `CreateElement` and `cloneNode` and `appendChild`, its very intuitive. Once you have the document created you just do `MyDocument.XML` and it outputs the whole document as a string.

Comment: i changed the tag to VBA instead of VBS. thank you for the clarification. it is also mentioned that im walking into someone elses code, and maybe they were trying VBA. when i was messing around with ASP, it was just VBS at the time. so there is probably some disconnect on my knowledge level and understanding of how the formats have changed over the years. thank you all for your help

Comment: @VincentDiRosa ASP is a server-side framework that uses VBScript, VBA is a hosted programming language that relies on a host such as any of the Office Suite of applications (Excel, Word, Powerpoint, Access etc). There is a great deal of difference between how the two are used. Clarifying how you execute the code would help.

Comment: @user692942 Certainly. I'm trying to pull a list from a software suite we have that details timelines, parts and other manufacturing dependencies to automatically write itself into excel, then turn that excel file into a .ERP file so another software can read it and change it self based on the information in the excel file. currently the code listed above is being run in a macro on the excel program so that it will auto compile once an update has been made, triggering the self sustaining chain of events. i hope this information helps

Comment: @VincentDiRosa "Excel macro" is all you needed to say. Would suggest taking that comment and updating the question so that is clear without others having to read the comments thread.

Comment: "it will auto compile once an update has been made" - do you mean this code is in an event handler?  "I can't seem to get this to compile" - what exactly is the problem when compiling?

Comment: `.Range("A2:A" & GetLastRow("Sheet1"))` would be better as `.Range("A2:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)` since Sheet1 might not always be the ActiveSheet.

Comment: @TimWilliams there is an error message sometimes when trying to run the code. but the message usually changes every instance and sometimes there wont be any message and the code will run infinitely. it will always be 1 sheet that is being used. i suppose you could say this is an event handler, but as stated in my OP, this is code im walking into done by someone else. Would it be beneficial to describe the process flow for you?

Comment: Yes it’s difficult to diagnose without some context

Comment: What's the initial value of `x`, and don't you need to reset that at some point?  It's difficult to follow the logic of that inner loop.

Comment: So what we are trying to do is have an export from a program (Delfoi) that generates itself (the file is an XML) then we need this macro to essential recreate that file in a specific format and save the new file as a .ERP file that can be read by our laser. this process needs to be automatic. the Macro needs to recreate the info in the cells, so it has to read the old ones then write the new ones and any time it hits a null or blank cell, it needs to repeat until it reaches a "Ture" value (we use Ture do to a typo that happened some months ago that never got corrected) then end loop

Comment: You're looping every cell in ColA as `FileName`, but then you also have an inner loop on ColD starting at `FileName` using x as an offset (but you never reset x?)  It's pretty unclear why it would be structured like that (and without knowing what your data looks like it's difficult to propose a fix)  If you can add a screenshot (maybe outline some blocks which should each end up in a different file) that would help a lot

Answer (score 0):

Consider use a template with placeholders that you can replace with values.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub macro1()

    ' XML Template
    Const TMPL = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8"" standalone=""yes""?>" & vbCrLf & _
    "<ErpExchange xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xmlns:xsd=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"">" & vbCrLf & _
    "    <Orders>" & vbCrLf & _
    "        <ErpOrder>" & vbCrLf & _
    "            <ImportType>NewOrder</ImportType>" & vbCrLf & _
    "            <OrderNumber>{NO}</OrderNumber>" & vbCrLf & _
    "            <TargetDate>{DATE}</TargetDate>" & vbCrLf & _
    "            <ProductionStrategy>TargetDateOrder</ProductionStrategy>" & vbCrLf & _
    "            <Automatic>False</Automatic>" & vbCrLf & _
    "            <Parts>" & vbCrLf & _
    "                <ErpPart>" & vbCrLf & _
    "                    <BysoftCode>{CODE}</BysoftCode>" & vbCrLf & _
    "                    <Debit>{DEBIT}</Debit>" & vbCrLf & _
    "                    <Measure>Inch</Measure>" & vbCrLf & _
    "                </ErpPart>" & vbCrLf & _
    "            </Parts>" & vbCrLf & _
    "        </ErpOrder>" & vbCrLf & _
    "    </Orders>" & vbCrLf & _
    "</ErpExchange>"
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cell As Range, XML
    Dim s As String, FSO As Object
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    ' scan sheet
    For Each cell In ws.Range("A2:A" & ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

        With cell
            If .Offset(, 4).Value = "Ture" Then Exit For
        
            s = TMPL
            s = Replace(s, "{NO}", .Offset(, 1).Value) ' order number
            s = Replace(s, "{DATE}", Format(.Offset(, 2).Value, "yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss")) ' target date
            s = Replace(s, "{CODE}", .Offset(, 3).Value) ' BysoftCode
            s = Replace(s, "{DEBIT}", .Offset(, 4).Value) ' Debit
        End With
        
        Set XML = FSO.CreateTextFile( _
                    filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "ERP" & ".erp", _
                    Overwrite:=True)
        
        XML.Write s
        XML.Close
        
        ' process xml
        MsgBox s
    Next
End Sub
```